# Make sure no two rows contain identical values in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table and I want to make sure that no two rows can be alike.

So, for example, this table would be valid:

```
 user_id |   printer
---------+-------------
       1 | LaserWriter
       4 | LaserWriter
       1 | ThinkJet
       2 | DeskJet
```

But this table would not be:

```
 user_id |   printer
---------+-------------
       1 | LaserWriter
       4 | LaserWriter
       1 | ThinkJet     <--error (duplicate row)
       2 | DeskJet
       1 | ThinkJet     <--error (duplicate row)
```

This is because the last table has two instances of `1 | ThinkJet`.

So, `user_id` can be repeated (i.e. `1`) and printer can be repeated (i.e. `LaserWriter`) but once a record like `1 | ThinkJet` is entered once that combination cannot be entered again.

How can I prevent such occurrences in a Postgresql 11.5 table?

I would try experimenting with SQL code but alas I am still new on the matter.

**Please note this is for `INSERT`ing data into the table, not `SELECT`ing it.** Like a constraint iirc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's your script

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD CONSTRAINT some_constraint PRIMARY KEY(user_id,printer);

INSERT INTO tableA(user_id, printer)
VALUES
   (
      1,
      'LaserWriter'
   ) 
ON CONFLICT (user_id, printer) 
DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

Comment: alter your table first.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but if I've already made a constraint to make the user_id and printer columns the primary key why do i need to add the extra `ON CONFLICT`...`DO NOTHING;` parts?

Comment: It sounds like you're getting your current problem sorted out. Going forward, you may find situations where you want uniqueness, or some other constraint, on something other than a primary key. Postgres has all kinds of options to explore, including CHECK, UNIQUE and domains.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS

Comment: @MorrisdeOryx Yes, but in this table specifically I will only keep it to these two columns (all other constraints are all sorted out already). I do see this being useful in other tables/columns, though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT. For example:

```
SELECT user_id, DISTINCT printer FROM my_table;
```

That's all. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this only *shows* distinct records, I can still insert identical records into the table, which is what I don't want to be able to do.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Got it. You need to check your printer column as unique in the database. That way the You won't be able to insert a duplicate record.

Comment: Well, I could do that, however I'd like to have duplicate printer entries and duplicate user_id entires, however I don't want to have the same user_id/printer record twice. I have updated my example to clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry English is not my main language. I will try. Let's take a new table. `user_id` = `1` and `printer` = `ThinkJet` in the first row. If you try that again (`1` and `ThinkJet`) it will work normally. **I want it so it errors out if you try adding that combination again.** If you add `user_id` = `1` and `printer` = `LaserWriter`, that works since that combination is not already used. If you add `user_id` = `2` and `printer` = `ThinkJet` that will work since that combination is not already used either. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When creating the table I needed to specify the two columns as UNIQUE. Observe:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (user_id INT, printer VARCHAR(20), UNIQUE (user_id, printer));
```

Now, here are my results:

```
=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'LaserWriter');
INSERT 0 1

=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4, 'LaserWriter');
INSERT 0 1

=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'ThinkJet');
INSERT 0 1

=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'DeskJet');
INSERT 0 1

=# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'ThinkJet');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_user_id_printer_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, printer)=(1, ThinkJet) already exists.

=# SELECT * FROM foo;
 user_id |   printer   
---------+-------------
       1 | LaserWriter
       4 | LaserWriter
       1 | ThinkJet
       2 | DeskJet
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a series of steps (assuming there is no already assigned unique key).

1. Add a temporary column to make each row unique.
2. Assign a value to the new columns.
3. Remove the already existing duplicates.
4. Create a Unique or Primary Key on the composite columns.
5. Remove the temporary column.

```
alter table your_table add temp_unique integer unique;

do $$
declare
    row_num  integer = 1;
    c_assign cursor for
        select temp_unique 
          from your_table
           for update;
begin 
    for rec in c_assign
    loop
       update your_table 
          set temp_unique = row_num
        where current of c_assign;
       row_num = row_num + 1;
    end loop; 
end; 
$$

delete from your_table ytd
 where exists ( select 1
                  from your_table ytk
                 where ytd.user_id = ytk.user_id
                   and ytd.printer = ytk.printer
                   and ytd.temp_unique > ytk.temp_unique 
              )  ; 

alter table your_table add constraint id_prt_uk unique (user_id, printer);

alter table your_table drop temp_unique;
```

Comment: This probably works but this is way over what my SQL knowledge is. \*dizzy\* thanks for the help regardless